# Save HTML form schema to JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms

Is there any way to save HTML Form schema to JSON?

E.g. when I have something like this

```
<form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

How i can achieve somehting like this:

```
[
  {
    field: 'input',
    type: 'text',
    name: 'firstname'
  },
  {
    field: 'input',
    type: 'text',
    name: 'lastname'
  },
]
```

I dont mean that it has to be exact output as above, but how I can achieve something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to do something like this. You can iterate through form `elements` collection of elements, and use every element to extract necessary information.

In code below I used `Array.prototype.map` method, but maybe it would be more convenient to go with simple `for` loop. It would give you more room for customization.

```js
function serializeSchema(form) {
    return [].map.call(form.elements, function(el) {
        return {
            type: el.type,
            name: el.name,
            value: el.value
        };
    });
};

var form = document.querySelector('form'),
    schema = serializeSchema(form);

alert(JSON.stringify(schema, null, 4));
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Test">
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <select name="age" id="">
        <option value="123" selected>123</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" name ="agree" value="1" checked> agree
</form>
```

Also one more note. What you are trying to achieve is very similar to what jQuery's [`$.fn.serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) method does (it doesn't collect `type`). However it's pretty simple to extend `serializeArray` to make it also return `type` of the elements.